# Need help looping through Ansible msg output

Tags: ansible

I need help going through the output of this task in ansible and ONLY pulling out the path for the "{{ item }}" being found.

Tried multiple ways and having very little success. Still learning ansible, and in this case, I'm trying to create a new directory based on the output of my inventory file. (the tail command for now because I only need to test it on 10 entries)

Playbook:
'''

```
  - name: Get the inventory file printout.
    command: tail "{{ build_dir }}{{ inventory_file }}"
    register: command_output

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ command_output.stdout_lines }}"

  - name : Find the RPMs in "{{ build_dir }}"
    find:
      paths: "{{ build_dir }}"
      patterns: "{{ item }}.rpm"
      recurse: yes
    with_items:
      - "{{ command_output.stdout_lines }}"
    register: found_pkgs

  - name: Just the Path for each Found Pkgs.
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop:
      - "{{ found_pkgs }}"
```

Output:

```
"msg": {                                                                                                           
    "changed": false,                                                                                              
    "msg": "All items completed",                                                                                  
    "results": [                                                                                                   
        {                                                                                                          
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",                                                                            
            "changed": false,                                                                                      
            "examined": 15029,                                                                                     
            "failed": false,                                                                                       
            "files": [                                                                                             
                {                                                                                                  
                    "atime": 1629933434.2974539,                                                                   
                    "ctime": 1629814445.3359122,                                                                   
                    "dev": 64773,                                                                                  
                    "gid": 70000,                                                                                  
                    "gr_name": "engineering",                                                                      
                    "inode": 469762133,                                                                            
                    "isblk": false,                                                                                
                    "ischr": false,                                                                                
                    "isdir": false,                                                                                
                    "isfifo": false,                                                                               
                    "isgid": false,                                                                                
                    "islnk": false,                                                                                
                    "isreg": true,                                                                                 
                    "issock": false,                                                                               
                    "isuid": false,                                                                                
                    "mode": "0644",                                                                                
                    "mtime": 1629814445.3359122,                                                                   
                    "nlink": 1,                                                                                    
                    "path": "<REDACTED>/newISO/repos/zeek/packages/zeek-btest-4.0.2-1.1.x86_64.rpm",
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `json_query` [filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) to extract the path of each file from `results[]`. A `set_fact` task such as below should do:

```yaml
    - name: save the files path in file_names var
      set_fact:
        file_paths: "{{ found_pkgs | json_query('results[].files[].path') }}"

    - name: show file names
      debug:
        var: file_paths
```